# Source code error in webpage caused by revolution slider

Tags: html, wordpress, revolution-slider

at the moment that i check the source code of my web page it shows this errors (view-source:http:// www. lamina-galvanizada.com/)

any idea what is causing them? i cant let the page having those

[revolution slider errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27NVT.png)

it also shows this and says theres a missing nav tag open

[missing tag in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oSVS.png)

any idea into how to solve this? thanks

Comment: Could you add the relevant section of page source code to your answer?

Comment: The most important javascript error come from foundation.min.js library located in your theme **Thine**: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FoundationParams`. I think that you could ask your theme support to solve your issues, opening a ticket. is the best option… viva Mexico :)